# Olympus M.Zuiko 100-400mm lens on a Panasonic GH4?

Tags: lens, telephoto

The lens in consideration is the [Olympus M.Zuiko Digital ED 100-400mm f/5-6.3 IS Lens](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1576153-REG/olympus_v315070bu000_m_zuiko_digital_ed_100_400mm.html) for a Panasonic GH4 which I already own.

- I have reviewed the [x lens, y camera question/answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y), but looks like
  Panasonic/Olympus mostly agree on a standard so I think I am okay
  there.
- The lens is in the [Panasonic GH4 compatibility list](https://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/dsc/connect/gh4.html).
- This [detailed review](https://mirrorlesscomparison.com/micro-four-thirds-lenses/olympus-100-400mm-vs-panasonic-100-400mm/) paints the Olympus lens a bit better than
  the [equivalent focal length Panasonic lens](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1211984-REG/panasonic_100_400mm_g_series_lens.html).
- The GH4 doesn't support the "Dual optical image stabilization" of the
  Panasonic lens.
- The Olympus lens is also a bit cheaper.

Are there any hidden unknowns that an experienced photographer can point out. Is this Olympus lens ultimately a good choice or is it best to stick with the same brand?

Comment: I guess the whole point of the Panasonic compatibility list is to reveal those "hidden unknowns", no?

Comment: @osullic, I hope so. I just figured it would be prudent to ask the community before I dive in.